# kurento's remote stream is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, kurento

I installed kurento-media-server-6.0 and I turn on media-server and Hello World!(Tutorial 1, Version - node.js). But when I click a start button, Remote stream does not work.

Console >>> TypeError: videoStream.addEventListener is not a function

Please give help to me, who knows why this error happens.

Comment: nodejs version is v0.10.40
npm  version is 2.14.1

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the appropriate js dependencies at the browser side. This should be fixed executing 'bower install' in the root folder of the tutorial (as specified in the corresponding tutorial documentation), in case of a fresh installation; or executing 'bower update' in case you had the tutorial installed previously.

In addition, double check that tht tutorial is in the appropriate version (6.0.0 tag). Sometimes mixing 5.x client code with 6.x media server generates that type of problems with dependencies.

Comment: Thanks, it was problem that firefox version was lower.