# Hello World (WebRTC in loopback) Remote video stream is not working in Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

Tags: kurento

[Kurento Hello World client](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.10.0/tutorials/js/tutorial-helloworld.html) is integrated with the Kurento Media Server. After configuring Kurento server and client, the application able to connect to the URL https://localhost:8443/. But Remote video stream is not working in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: This client is using Secure WebSocket (WSS). Have you activate your kurento server using wss? To activate the wss follow the guide line @ https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/6.10.0/features/security.html

Comment: Another might be the problem in your browser version. Look the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32347543/4050015